# mongosh users can connect to authorization enabled database and enable telemetry

Tags: database, mongodb, docker, security, docker-compose

using `mongosh` anonymous users can connect to MongoDB server even tho i enabled security authorization, they can enable and disable telemetry!

how can i make this more secure. my mongodb is running inside a docker container.

Comment: How does the unauthenticated connection enable telemetry?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Even without credentials you can connect to a MongoDB, however you cannot execute any command, apart from harmless commands like `db.help()` or `db.getCommands()`

I know only one solution to prevent this. You must run MongoDB with `net.tls.mode: requireTLS` and authenticate users with x.509 certificate.

Telemetry is enabled in users home folder, this you cannot change either.